# HttpContext.RewritePath breakes buildin IIS gzip

Tags: iis, gzip, rewritepath

Hello.

I am using `HttpContext.RewritePath` to direct request to inner site folders depending from request and host.

Problem:
When I do any request that requires RewritePath for any static file that is cached and GZIPped by IIS, I get in response original non-compressed file content with `Content-Encoding: gzip` header, which leads to “Content decoding has failed” error.
But when I do same request but with full directory path (in that case RewritePath is skipped in my code) I get right gzipped content with `Content-Encoding: gzip`.

E.g.:
Situation with error:
Request url: `localhost/lib/ext_3.4.0/resources/css/ext-all.css`
Request path is rewrited using HttpContext.RewritePath to: `localhost/_sites/mainSite/lib/ext_3.4.0/resources/css/ext-all.css`

First response is not gzipped - usual IIS behavior. When I press ctrl+F5, I get “Content decoding has failed” error. By using Fiddler2 I can see that response content is not gzipped and it contains `Content-Encoding: gzip` header.

Situation without error:
Request url: `localhost/_sites/mainSite/lib/ext_3.4.0/resources/css/ext-all.css`
Request path is not rewrited because it is not needed.

First response is not gzipped again. When I press ctrl+F5, I get normal file content. By using Fiddler2 I can see that response content is gzipped, size is 5 times less and it contains `Content-Encoding: gzip` header.

I can't throw away RewritePath and I need IIS gzip. Is there any way to make them friends?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? We have the same problem as you, i.e. rewriting the path of a static file, and that makes IIS to send the file uncompressed while it should have been compressed.